# How can I include variable values in tangled files?

Tags: org-mode

I have a variable defined in my heading that I would like to use in one text source block that I tangle to a file.

Example:

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:  :var foo=222
:END:

... use foo in some shell scripts ...

#+BEGIN_SRC text :tangle config-file
I want to include value of FOO here
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Org header variables are intended for use in the evaluation of a code block, not when a block is tangled to a file. However, you might be able to write an export function for the tangling that does what you want. A related problem and example code is at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/can-i-insert-a-prefix-to-org-babel-source-code-lines-on-export

Answer (score 3):

#### Use built-in `:noweb` functionality

1. Add named elisp `src` block to return the variable value.

   ```
   #+NAME: foo-value
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports none 
     foo
   #+END_SRC

   #+RESULTS: foo-value
   : 222
   ```

   > **Note:** I choose `elisp` for this example because `elisp` code is enabled by default. This trick will also work with other languages, e.g.`ruby` and `python`.
2. Add `:noweb yes` header to the `src` block that will be tangled.

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC text :noweb yes :tangle config-file 
     I want to include value of <<foo-value()>> here.
   #+END_SRC
   ```

   > When the file is tangled, the `<<foo-value()>>` will be replaced with `222`.

---

Below is the updated version of your example code:

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:  :var foo=222
:END:

#+NAME: foo-value
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports none 
  foo
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: foo-value
: 222

#+BEGIN_SRC text :noweb yes :tangle config-file 
  I want to include value of <<foo-value()>> here.
#+END_SRC
```

---

> **The code in this answer was tested using**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.1
>   org-mode version: 9.1.14

---

Thanks for asking a great question!
Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the following does what you want:

```
* Test  
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:  :var foo=222
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :tangle tangle.txt
echo $foo
#+END_SRC
```

I can tangle this with `C-c C-v t`, which produces the file `tangle.txt`:

> foo='222'
>   echo $foo

You have to specify what kind of code your code block is. In my example, a bash script. If you just specify text as you did, org won't know what syntax to use to define your variable.